# Admin.E108 when customizing admin interface

Tags: python, django, admin

I received this error:

```
ERRORS:
<class 'bjjtournament_app.admin.MemberAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[3]' refers to 'Group1', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'MemberAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'bjjtournament_app.Competitors'.
```

I think the error is in `admin.py`:

```
class MemberAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ["group_label"]
admin.site.unregister(Group1)
admin.site.register(Group1, MemberAdmin)

def __str__(self):
    return self.group_label
```

Can someone explain to me what the error is about?